# Make Jython JFrame that cannot be closed

Tags: python, jframe, jython

I'm writing a little script for TopSpin, a program to acquire and process NMR data. While the script is running the user should not select a different dataset in TopSpin. Therefore I wanted to open a Popup screen displaying a message.

The script we are talking about, will take some time to finish it's task, so if a user closes the popup, the message will not be visible anymore and another staff member could - unknowingly - cause some problems by selecting different datasets. That's the reason why I had the idea of implementing a popup window that cannot be closed by the user.

When the script starts it's task it will run `popup.show()` and after having finished it will run `popup.hide()`. How could I do this in Jython?

```
from javax.swing import *

def test():
    frame = JFrame("Hello StackOverflow")
    frame.setSize(300, 300)
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(None)
    frame.show()

    # Do some work

    frame.hide() 

test()
```